# adding a custom HTMLElement in Typescript

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Hi I am new to angular and this may seem obvious to someone with more experience, but i am trying to add a custom html element to a page on button click. I cant figure out how.

My html and ts files

TS FILE:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-conter',
  templateUrl: './conter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./conter.component.css']
})
export class ConterComponent extends HTMLElement {
   _ref;
   constructor(id: string) {
    super();
    this.draggable = true;
    this.setAttribute('(drag)', 'drag($event)');
    this.setAttribute('id', id);
   }
   @Input()
  counterValue = 0 ;
   drag(ev) {
     ev.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this);
   }
   protected validation() {
   }
  increment() {
    this.counterValue++;
  }
  decrement() {
    this.counterValue--;
  }
  setCounter(value) {
    this.counterValue = value;
      }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="cont">
<button (click)="increment()">+</button>
{{counterValue}}
<button (click)="decrement()">-</button>
</div>
```

where i add the element :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {
  }
  ngOnInit() {}
  generate() {

                  <-- Method where i want to add my HTMELement to the page
  }
```

Comment: Do you want to add html tag or custom tag like <custom> </custom> ?

Comment: use ngIf for showing custom element at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by below example

```
generate(){
 const template = document.createElement('template');
 document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(template);
}
```

But i think you need to add CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA in module look [here](https://hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2016/10/12/angular2-template-parse-errors-add-custom_elements_schema-to-the-ngmodule-schemas/) how to add it in module to avoid error.

Comment: Please add comment what's wrong in answer before voting down so i can improve answer.